# Struct - argument for 's' must be a bytes object but already is a bytes object

Tags: python, struct

I am currently trying to fix a bug in a package I am developing. The problem seems to be the struct.pack function that is throwing the error:

```
struct.error: argument for 's' must be a bytes object
```

I have attempted to use answers provided for this error on other SO answer pages, but can't seem to get anything to work, and the error persists.

Below is a simplified version of the inputs I have been dealing with as output by the package that replicates the error:

```
import struct

second_arg = b'LASF_Projection\x00'

print(type(second_arg))
struct.pack("<ssssssssssssssss",  *second_arg)
```

This results in the output:

```
    <class 'bytes'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/pyfor/anothersandbox.py", line 7, in <module>
    struct.pack(b"<ssssssssssssssss",  *second_arg)
struct.error: argument for 's' must be a bytes object
```

My suspicion is that, when unpacked, *second_arg is no longer in bytes format, and is throwing the error. Is this suspicion correct, and if so is it possible to convert the unpacked parts of second_arg into byte format on the fly?

Comment: When you unpack `bytes` you get `int`s, same as when you iterate `bytes`.

Comment: what result do you expect for this data ? How about `pack("<16s",  second_arg)` but it gives the same `b'LASF_Projection\x00'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct.  A bytes is a sequence of ints in range(256).  In 3.6:

```
>>> [*b'LASF_Projection\x00']
[76, 65, 83, 70, 95, 80, 114, 111, 106, 101, 99, 116, 105, 111, 110, 0]
```

Those ints are what you are passing.